# how to read a csv file with a JSON feature using python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a csv file that contains a JSON feature as shown below dataframe

id |   Date  | Session

```json
001 | 29/8/2019 | [{"start":451;"end":459;"duration":13};{"start":522;"end":528;"duration":11};{"start":568;"end":575;"duration":12};{"start":595;"end":604;"duration":14};{"start":1194;"end":1210;"duration":21}]

002 | 27/8/2019 | [{"start":64;"end":65;"duration":6};{"start":451;"end":456;"duration":10};
{"start":513;"end":516;"duration":8};{"start":537;"end":541;"duration":9};{"start":1208;"end":1215;"duration":12};{"start":1367;"end":1368;"duration":6}]
```

- Definition:

Hour01: The duration (in mins) of session within the 1st hour of the day, from 0001 to 0100 hr.
Hour02: The duration (in mins) of session within the 2nd hour of the day, from 0101 to 0200 hr. and so on
.
.
Hour23: The duration (in mins) of session within the 24th hour of the day, from 2301 to 2400 hr.

- Note 1: Each day starts with “0” minute and ends at “1440” minutes.
- Note 2: An additional “5 minutes” is added to the start of each Activity session.
- Note 3: An session is considered `VALID only WHEN {session minutes in {duration} is > 9 minutes}`.
- Note 4: For session that is <= 9 minutes, they will be disregarded, the duration of minutes discarded.

In scenario 1, we read the first row in the “Session” - `{"start"":451;""end"":459;””duration””:13;}` that shows that the Activity started at minute 451 and ended at minute 459 ==> this leads to `{459 – 551}` 8 minutes of Activity at the {Hour of day}, on that Date `{29/8/2019}` for that user ID`{ec296e97c0}`.

a. The Minute 451 starts in the “Hour 8” and 459 ends in “Hour 8”. So the total of Activity of “8 minutes” is read to “Hour 8” for that user (as shown below).
b. We add an additional “5 minutes” in the first slot (initial hour) for each Activity session. {8 + 5} 13 minutes are assigned to “Hour 8” (instead of 8 minutes) as shown below in the output.
This is a valid session and the duration of 13 minutes will be captured. (After applying Note 2 & 3 above).

2. Similarly, we assign all the segments {Session} and map them to the rightful Hours.

For scenario 2, When Session span over two or more consecutive Hours:

1. From the above example on the 4th session, `{""start"":595;""end"":604;""duration"":14}`.
   i. The Activity span over two hours `{10, 11}`.
   ii. Minutes “595 to 600” are assigned to “Hour10” & “600 to 604” to “Hour11”.
   (Note 2 & 3 are applied accordingly across each session)

2. Total minutes for each Hour `{Hr1…Hr24}` is derived and tabulated as per “Expected output”

Totally stuck in putting the above csv with JSON values in the below format:
EXPECTED –OUTPUT {as per the below format} showing 1 row as example of outcome

```
ID |   Date  |Hr01|Hr02|Hr03|Hr04|Hr05|Hr06|Hr07|Hr08|Hr09|Hr10|Hr11|.....|Hr24
001|27/8/2019|    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 13 | 11 | 22 | 33 |...
002|26/8/2019|...
```

Can any help to advice how to achieve this using `python`? I'm someone still weak in new in python and would really appreaciate if someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```py
import re

CSV_FILE = "file.csv"
CSV_OUTPUT_FILE = "output.csv"

file = open(CSV_OUTPUT_FILE, "w")
file.close()

with open(CSV_FILE, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line == "\n":
            continue
        seperaters = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(line) if ltr == "|"]
        id = line[: seperaters[0]].replace(" ", "")
        date = line[seperaters[0] + 1 : seperaters[1]].replace(" ", "")
        raw_data = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r"\d+", line[seperaters[1] + 1 :])]
        Hours = [100 * _ for _ in range(1, 25)]
        hours = [0 for _ in range(24)]
        data = []
        data_temp = []
        for i in range(len(raw_data)):
            if (i + 1) % 3:
                data_temp.append(raw_data[i])
            else:
                data_temp.append(raw_data[i])
                data.append(data_temp)
                data_temp = []
        for H in Hours:
            for d in data:
                if H - 100 <= d[0] <= H and H - 100 <= d[1] <= H:
                    if d[2] >= 9:
                        hours[int(H / 100) - 1] += d[2]
                elif H - 100 <= d[0] <= H and H <= d[1] <= H + 100:
                    if H - d[0] + 5 >= 9:
                        hours[int(H / 100) - 1] += H - d[0] + 5
                    if d[1] - H + 5 >= 9:
                        hours[int(H / 100)] += d[1] - H + 5
        with open(CSV_OUTPUT_FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write(str(id) + "|")
            file.write(str(date) + "|")
            for h in hours:
                if h:
                    file.write(str(h) + "|")
                else:
                    file.write("|")
            file.write("\n")
```

replace `file.csv` with your own file.